# Replay BGP Updates to Quagga

Tags: routes, bgp, quagga

I have a small setup where there are 3 connected ASes running Quagga, and I want to test this setup by replaying historical BGP data. How can I do this? I'd appreciate any thoughts and guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed a tool to replay past BGP updates.

Technical report is available on: http://caia.swin.edu.au/reports/160304A/CAIA-TR-160304A.pdf

BRT-v0.1 is available on: http://caia.swin.edu.au/tools/bgp/brt-0.1.tgz